# IIS / Proxy Issue: Error 12166 (local webpage)

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, iis, proxy

Iam trying to set up a local web site (with IIS in local Intranet).
Therefore i copied the content of the site to:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test

and i converted the folder Test into an application under Default Web Site in IIS. (port 80.)

If i now try to open the site in Browser via

`http://localhost/Test/Text.html`

i got some errors in my logfile:

`gs.client: get: http://localhost/Test/version.txt`

`System.Net Information: 0 : [8304] Der aktuelle Betriebssysteminstallationstyp ist "Client".`

`System.Net Information: 0 : [8304] RAS unterstützt: True`

`System.Net Error: 0 : [8304] Die Proxyeinstellungen für URI "http://localhost/Test/version.txt" können nicht abgerufen werden. Fehlercode: 12166`

`System.Net Information: 0 : [8304] Associating HttpWebRequest#6614365 with ServicePoint#42849418`

`System.Net Information: 0 : [8304] Associating Connection#63677697 with HttpWebRequest#6614365`

`System.Net Information: 0 : [8304] Connection#63677697 - Die Verbindung von 10.10.10.10:52350 mit 10.10.10.10:80 wurde hergestellt.`

`System.Net Information: 0 : [8304] Associating HttpWebRequest#6614365 with ConnectStream#59134297`

`System.Net Information: 0 : [8304] HttpWebRequest#6614365 - Request: GET /Test/version.txt HTTP/1.1`

`System.Net Information: 0 : [4820] ConnectStream#9144789::ConnectStream(Es wurden 5213 Bytes gepuffert.`)

`System.Net Information: 0 : [4820] Associating HttpWebRequest#34696492 with ConnectStream#9144789`

`System.Net Information: 0 : [4820] Associating HttpWebRequest#34696492 with HttpWebResponse#27293151`

`System.Net Error: 0 : [4820] Ausnahme in HttpWebRequest#34696492::GetResponse - Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (404) Nicht gefunden.`

`System.Net Error: 0 : [4820] Ausnahme in HttpWebRequest#34696492:: - Die Anfrage wurde abgebrochen: Die Anfrage wurde abgebrochen..`.

`gs.client: get.error: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (404) Nicht gefunden.`

how can this be solved

Thank you.

PS: This is the Logfile of IIS:

```
2014-03-31 08:56:29 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/ - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 3
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/OutageMap.html - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 1
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/geoserver-api/content/user.css - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 404 0 2 2
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/geoserver-api/content/OutageTable.css - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 404 0 2 2
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/img/menu_white_28x28.png - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 3
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 3
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/img/arrow_gray_28x28.png - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 2
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/img/close_12x12.png - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 1
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/main.css - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 5
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/img/arrow_white_28x28.png - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 2
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/img/search.png - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 1
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/img/search_30x50.png - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 3
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/img/oms-minimize.png - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 2
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/img/ajax_loader.gif - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 7
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/scripts/require.js - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 22
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/scripts/main.js - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0 0 130
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/geoserver-api/content/htmlTemplates.html - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 404 0 2 1
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/geoserver-api/content/configuration.js _=1396256191237 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 404 0 2 1
2014-03-31 08:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/geoserver-api/content/strings.js - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 404 0 2 1
2014-03-31 08:57:19 127.0.0.1 GET /OutageMap/version.txt - 80 - 127.0.0.1 - 200 0 0 0
2014-03-31 08:57:19 127.0.0.1 GET /OutageMap/geoserver-api/set/Reset - 80 - 127.0.0.1 - 404 0 2 1
2014-03-31 08:58:20 127.0.0.1 GET /OutageMap/version.txt - 80 - 127.0.0.1 - 200 0 0 1
2014-03-31 08:58:20 127.0.0.1 GET /OutageMap/geoserver-api/set/Reset - 80 - 127.0.0.1 - 404 0 2 0
2014-03-31 08:59:20 127.0.0.1 GET /OutageMap/version.txt - 80 - 127.0.0.1 - 200 0 0 1
2014-03-31 08:59:20 127.0.0.1 GET /OutageMap/geoserver-api/set/Reset - 80 - 127.0.0.1 - 404 0 2 0
2014-03-31 08:59:46 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/geoserver-api/content/OutageTable.css - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 404 0 64 1
2014-03-31 08:59:46 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/geoserver-api/content/user.css - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 404 0 2 1
2014-03-31 08:59:46 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/geoserver-api/content/htmlTemplates.html - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 404 0 2 1
2014-03-31 08:59:46 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/geoserver-api/content/configuration.js _=1396256386608 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 404 0 2 1
2014-03-31 08:59:46 127.0.0.1 GET /outageMap/geoserver-api/content/strings.js - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 404 0 2 0
2014-03-31 09:00:21 127.0.0.1 GET /OutageMap/version.txt - 80 - 127.0.0.1 - 200 0 0 1
2014-03-31 09:00:21 127.0.0.1 GET /OutageMap/geoserver-api/set/Reset - 80 - 127.0.0.1 - 404 0 2 0
```

Comment: Do you have proxy set on computer where you run gs.client? does gs.client use proxy set in IE? Do you have any access in IIS log?

Comment: How do you set proxy on computer where i run gs.client? how do i configure gs.client to use proxy?
i added IIS log ..

Thank you

Comment: From the log file I understand that call to `/OutageMap.version.txt` eneded with 200 (OK) but call to `OutageMap/geoserver-api/set/Reset` ended with 404 (Not Found). All calls to `geoserver-api` ends with 404. You should check if this application/content/url exists on the server. Also, you can check system proxy settings on the server using this command `netsh winhttp show proxy`.

Comment: netsh winhttp show proxy gives the following result:
WinHTTP-Proxysettings: Direct-Access <no Proxyserver>.